# How to implement child-objects in MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm trying to implement MVC in my next web-application project.

All examples I see (Phalcon, Laravel, etc.) seem to use different classes for each table in the database. This makes sense, but in the examples I can't find a real connection between the classes. In other words, no *child-objects* seem to be defined.

For example, for a forum web-app, you'd need Useraccounts, Categories, Topics and Comments. But these are not stand-alone objects. A topic would have one or more categories, a useraccount of the user that started the topic and several comments, which would each link to a useraccount as well.

Instead of having separate classes for each table, wouldn't it make more sense to make it reflect the connection between each other?  So for example, a Topic object contains an array of Comment-objects.

Like this :

```
               Application
                    |
Categories ---  Topics ---  Useraccounts (topicstarter)
                    |
                Comments  ---  Useraccounts (commenter)
```

- Is this the way people use MVC or should I consider each table (class) as an
  entirely separate entity?
- Does it make sense to have an Application object/class that contains
  everything else, or is this really not necessary?

Comment: What you're describing is an ORM (Object-Relational Mapping relating to Data Entities). That has absolutely nothing to do with the MVC design pattern.

Comment: But the models and controllers do need to know about their child-objects, don't they? For example to show the number of comments in each topic. How is this implemented then with MVC ?

Comment: By "model" are you referring to the Entity objects or the ViewModels? (Remember to never use Entity Models as top-level ViewModels, even if they have the same interface). Most ORMs will provide "navigation" members for accessing and enumerating parent and child relationships. Please post more information regarding the specific ORM you're using and any classes it generated, and if you're using the code-first or database-first approach.

Comment: Database first. I'm not using an ORM. I'm sorry, it's hard to explain, as I'm not really sure what I mean myself. I guess my basic quesion is : are parent-child and lookup relations between different kind of objects reflected in the model in MVC or not ?  I can imagine a parent model that needs to add itself to the database, but also its children.  Would I use 2 different models for this, one for the parent and one for each child, or could this be done in 1 operation,  where the parent class calls 'save' for each of its child objects?